# Double Foreach unexpected result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays, both associative;

```
ArrayUneaten ( lemon=> 7, banana=>6, apple=>10)//the units of UNeaten fruit
ArrayOrdered (lemon =>10, strawberry =>10, Kiwi=>0, Apple=>20, Banana=>6) // the units of ordered fruit
```

I want to create a third array (numeric is fine if in the same order as ArrayOrdered) 
of all fruit options and the % of Fruit Eaten (compared to Fruit Ordered).

(NB for other reasons if Ordered Value = 0, %eaten = 0%)

(NB2, note that % desired for strawberries is 100, no strawberries are uneaten, 10 ordered, therefore 10 have been eaten)

So desired Array

```
ArrayEatenPercentage (70, 100, 0, 50, 0)
```

My coding attempt

```
$CompletedPercentagesArray = array ();

foreach( $ArrayOrdered as $fruitOrdered => $unitsOrdered) {
    if ($unitsOrdered == 0){
        //if it's zero it's never been selected
        $completedPercentage = 0;
    }
    foreach( $ArrayUneaten as $fruitUneaten => $unitsUneaten) {
        if ( $fruitUneaten == $fruitOrdered){
            // ($totalCardsChosen = $timesSelected*25; - please ignore)
            $percentageUneaten = 100*($fruitUneaten/$unitsOrdered);
            $percentageEaten = 100 - $percentageUneaten;
            $completedPercentage = round ($percentageEaten, 1);
        }
        else {//if this is true then it's been selected and been finished
            $completedPercentage = 100;
        }
    }
    array_push( $completedPercentagesArray, $completedPercentage ); //this adds the variable to the array
}
print_r($completedPercentagesArray);
```

Current output is unexpected.

Only last value of ArrayUneaten is processed correctly.

The other values return 100%.

```
ArrayEatenPercentage (100, 100, 100, 50, 100)
```

Comment: You should *show* the current output, as well as the expected output.

Comment: You use $fruitsUneaten in the code and ArrayUneaten in your examples. It might be that you have used the wrong name somewhere in your code.

Comment: seems to me that your code does not use the same array variables you are using in your example. For instance, `foreach( $fruitUneaten as $fruitsUneaten => $unitsUneaten)` is using `$fruitUneaten` which has not been mentioned in the code previously. The same is happening in `array_push( $completedPercentagesArray, $completedPercentage )` where you are pushing to `$completedPercentagesArray` instead of `ArrayEatenPercentage`. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: thanks, those were just typos (now corrected) from transferring from my real code (otherwise my output would be undefined variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all fruits are in the "ordered" array, you could try something like this:

```
$results = array();
foreach( $arrayOrdered as $fruit => $numOrdered ) {
    if( Isset( $arrayUneaten[$fruit] ) ) {
        $numEaten = $numOrdered - $arrayUneaten[$fruit];
    } else {
        $numEaten = $numOrdered;
    }
    if( $numOrdered > 0 ) {
        $percentEaten = $numEaten / $numOrdered * 100;
    } else {
        $percentEaten = 0;
    }
    $results[$fruit] = array( 'eaten' => $numEaten, 'percent' => $percentEaten );
}
```

Your result array would be keyed on fruit and have both the absolute amount eaten and the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You should have added break; at the end of if ( $fruitUneaten == $fruitOrdered){ condition block. Otherwise unless the current fruit is the last element(which is apple) of $ArrayUneaten, $completedPercentage becomes always 100, because on the last iteration of the inner loop exection goes to that else block.

Comment: Thanks, although I went with the above because it came through first and worked. Not sure which of the two codes would be faster or more stable.